# Ionic 3 update the database on Firebae

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm trying to update the 'cash' value on database with the following code.

```
updateCash() {
    const userId = this.authCtrl.showUser().uid;
    this.afDatabase.database.ref(`users/${userId}/userInfos`).transaction(eventSnapshot => {
      eventSnapshot.cash += 100;
      this.afDatabase.list(`users/${userId}/userInfos`).push(eventSnapshot.cash);
    });
  }
```

But something goes wrong and saving like that.

[image]

How can i solve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
updateCash() {
    const userId = this.authCtrl.showUser().uid;
    this.afDatabase.database.ref(`users/${userId}/userInfos`).update({
        cash:200}).then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
}
```